# Disabling developer details at top of new file in xcode4

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi please can anyone one help me in disabling developer details getting inserted by default at top of each new file created in xcode4, thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry this is no where related to my question...if your comment did have tick or wrong buttons definitely i would have given you the right acceptance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy Apple's templates and create your own versions without the header.
http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/making-custom-templates-for-xcode-4-march-2011/

> Go to /Developer/Library/Xcode
>   Select Templates/ folder, copy it
>   Go to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode
>   Paste the Templates/ folder as a sub-folder